# Convert Object to String

Tags: php

I have an object which gets a String. I want to compare it with a String and I don't know how to do it.
My source is something like it:

```
$field = $this->form->getFieldset('profile');
$website = "Web site";

if ($field->label == $website){
   echo "good";
}else{
   echo "bad";
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error? What is the problem?

Comment: use strcmp(string str1,string str2) ?!

Comment: I could use strcmp but $field->label is an Object and I need two String to use this method then how can I convert it into a String?

Comment: Please show the output of `var_dump($field->label)` or something similar, so maybe we'll understand the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't really understand the problem but you could convert it to an array using `get_object_vars`.

This is assuming that $field->label is actually a property rather than an object?

```
$field = $this->form->getFieldset('profile');
$website = "Web site";
$array = get_object_vars($field);

if ($array['label'] == $website) {
    echo 'Hoorah!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the result of gettype($field->label) is an object, you have to implement the magic method __toString()